# iOS Swift WebView issues

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiwebview, swift4

[image: StoryBoard Image]

I am new to iOS programming and trying my hands on making simple `TableViewCell` based app on click of which I open a `webView` with a dynamic URL.

In my main.storyboard, I have added a `UIViewController`, in which I have added `Webview` and `NavigationBar`.

1. The webView always opens up in full screen. So if I add a Navigation bar or back button, it does not show up in the view.
2. How can I navigate back to my table view page which contains a list of items, from the webView?

**My code:**

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class WebViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate {

    var webView: WKWebView!
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        title = webView.title
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let url = URL(string: webURL)!
        print(url)
        webView.load(URLRequest(url: url))
    }

    override func loadView() {
        webView = WKWebView()
        webView.navigationDelegate = self
        view = webView
    }
}
```

3. Right now, in above code, I have added webView as a simple variable.
   As soon as I make it an `@IBOutlet` and link to this controller, the code throws `SIGBART error`. Any reason?
4. I want to use navigations methods of webview like:

   ```
   @IBAction func backAction(sender: AnyObject) {
       if webView.canGoBack {
           webView.goBack()
       }
   }

   @IBAction func forwardAction(sender: AnyObject) {
       if webView.canGoForward {
           webView.goForward()
       }
   }

   @IBAction func refreshAction(sender: AnyObject) {
       webView.reload()
   }

   @IBAction func stopAction(sender: AnyObject) {
       webView.stopLoading()
   }
   ```

   but since I am not able to add WebView as an outlet, the above methods do not work for me.

TableController code from where I am performing segue on click of a row:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "recipeWebView", sender: self)
}
```

Comment: you need to embed your tableview in UINavigationController and on cell click push the ViewController with WebView in it.

Comment: add the code of controller from where you are pushing on webViewController

Comment: How are you navigating from first viewcontroller to 2nd view controller?

Comment: Updated info with table controller code

Comment: which type of segue it is show or present?

Comment: @sanjaykmwt I have added Storyboard image in the above post.

Comment: @RajeshKumarR I am using segue to move from one controller to another

Comment: webview outlet is connected properly?

Comment: Yes @RajeshKumarR, it was connected properly. The issue was with navigation controller link in between main table view controller and UI view controller.

Comment: @Nimesh is "recipeWebView" identified of the segue from tableviewcontroller to navigation controller?

Comment: @RajeshKumarR Yes

Answer (score -1):

Yes, as you have not added the navigation controller since the navigation bar couldn't perform.

Follow this type-> Table view-> navigation contoller -> uiviewcontroller -> webview

let me know if it is helpful?

Comment: I would like to, but I do not have enough reputation here.. :D